# Kafka Consumer instances are not reading from partition when the instance which were consuming got crashed

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 3 Consumer instances linked with one Consumer Group. As far as i understood and found we can't have Consumer instances more than no. of Partition in a topic.
I have only one partition in the Topic. So Only one Kafka Consumer instance is consuming messages in three instances of a group. But my worry is when that Consumer gets crashed then the other consumer instances should start reading from that partition, but its not happening.

Comment: Check out https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html

Comment: Also the consumer configs session.timeout.ms and heartbeat.interval.ms and max.poll.interval.ms

Answer (score 0):

Below things you can check to debug further -

1. After the crash , new messages are published to be consumed
2. After the crash consumer rebalance should get triggered (check the
   server logs) and the new partition assignment should happen

Comment: I have each thread running for each consumer instances in a Consumer Group. Lets say i have 3 Consumers in a Group and each consumer is running in a thread . I have only one topic with one partition that is being assigned to consumer1, Its consumed message 1 from that partition which is having 90 records. After that i am suspending the thread of consumer 1 having hoped that the remaining messages will be consumed by some other Consumer in a Group.

Comment: But its not consuming by other Consumers. For your information i am manually saving the consumer offset in a flat file. And i am passing the instance of ConsumerRebalanceListener while subscribing the topic in consumer side.

Comment: consumer.subscribe(topics,new MyConsumerRebalanceListener(consumer));

Comment: I could see in the consumer logs when Consumer1 is down it is not triggering the Consumer Rebalance its just sending and Receiving heartbeat.

Comment: And moreover that consumer1 is still sending and receiving heartbeat . I've just suspended the thread which is running the consumer1. So could that be a reason of not triggering consumer Rebalance because still consumer 1 is alive ???

Comment: I guess i'm receiving heartbeat response from the Group Coordinator for all the Consumer Instances thats why rebalancing is not triggering. If possible please tell me the way to close one consumer in a Consumer Group. So i can check whether other Consumer in a Group is picking its partition or not.

Comment: how are you concluding consumer1 is down ?

Comment: If you're using a flat file with multiple consumers (JVM's). It might not read the updated data properly from the file.